# Оптимизиация кода

Tags: kotlin

```
fun downloadPhotos(list: List<String>) {
        viewState.progressLoading(0)

        val channel=Channel<Int>()
        async (Dispatchers.IO) { DownloadFile.photo(list, channel) }
            .invokeOnCompletion {
                launch {
                    it?.let {UtilsException(it); viewState.errorMessage("Нет доступа к папкам, выберите новую директорию")}
                    viewState.hide()
                }
            }

        job=launch {
            for (str in list){
                val progress=(100/list.size)*channel.receive()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ viewState.progressLoading( progress ) }
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ viewState.hide() }
        }
    }
```

Здравствуйте всем. Как можно оптимизировать данный код с используемыми корутинами